# Is there a method using Powershell to remove a "Backup Item" from within a vault in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, backup

I'm currently running into a bit of a problem with Azure.  My organization has several Recovery Service Vaults, one of which contians 6 backup items, within these items there are varying numbers of backups.  One that I need to remove contains backups for SQL databases (not VM's, SQL DB backups).  The only method through the GUI to remove these is doing them one at a time but we have hundreds that need to go.

I have done some research but couldn't find a method in removing a specific backup item, just click methods for removing backups from within the Backup Item one at a time through the point and click method.  I have found powershell solutions for removing the entire vault but as there are backup items in there we want to preserve, this won't work.

Does anyone know of a powershell method to remove an entire backup item or at least remove all the backups from within a backup item so that I may then manually remove the backup item instead of going through hundreds of these through ye' ol' point-and-click?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL in Azure VM you can use the following.

```
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "ressource group name" -Name "vault name"
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVMAppContainer -Status Registered

foreach ($container in $containers)
{
    $items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType MSSQL
    foreach ($item in $items)
    {
        Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -item $item -RemoveRecoveryPoints -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the snippet I was using to delete Azure SQL long term backups:

```
# We need to set recovery services context to work with recovery vault
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name %VaultName%
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
# Get protection containers to work with those
$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -Status Registered
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $containers -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase
$availableBackups = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $item
$availableBackups # check existing items
foreach ($container in $containers) {
    $items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase
    ForEach ($item in $items) {
        Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -item $item -RemoveRecoveryPoints -ea SilentlyContinue
    }
    Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -Container $container
}
```

I'm not sure what would be the type for SQL backup for Azure Backup, though. AzureVm, probably.

Comment: Thanks!  Let me look this over and I'll see if I have any questions.  So far this looks like it just may do the trick!

Comment: This looks good but of course there's concern when I'm making mass removals.  I'm still relatively new to Powershell so I wonder, Is there a powershell method to echo what's happening during the disable step so I can observe the changes that are occurring?  Any recommendations on where/how I would enter that into the script?

Comment: you can just do `$containers` before foreach and check whats inside, or you could do `$items` before the nested foreach to examine whats happening there or you could user `-WhatIf` switch on cmdlets, they would spit out something like: this is what I was supposed to do, but didnt due to `-WhatIf`

Comment: I appreciate all your help and have upvoted your replies.  Unfortunately, our SQL is setup in "SQL in Azure VM" pilot and not the regular "AzureSQL".  Currently, there is no parameter for this available in powershell due to it being a pilot program... 

Everything you said and the advice you gave was top notch.  Much appreciated!

Comment: you can still try and work your way around this, so the algorithm would be to use network tools on the portal to capture the rest call and then you can use powershell to mimic that rest call, that would allow you to overcome that limitation.